# remove </tr> from html query

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jQuery I have a `myTable` string:

```
var myTable = "<table width='100%'><tr>";
```

After adding some data in `<td>`s to `myTable` like

```
myTable += <td>...</td><td>...</td>
```

then closing the table like:

```
myTable += "</tr><table>"
```

the `myTable` string is now:

```
"<table width='100%'><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr><table>"
```

Is it possible to remove the last (and only the last) `"</tr><table>"` from the table. The `<td>`s can contain nested `<table>`s.

So at the end `myTable` should be something like  `<table width='100%'><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td>"`.

Comment: you want to rmeove it from query or dom?

Comment: Is it important that it only removes the *last* `</tr></table>`, or in the case of nested tables, can it remove all of them?

Comment: but why you want to remove the closing tag ..it is required right..because that is the syntax..you cannot or should not try to remove the end closing tags...if you can tell us for what reason you want this then we an help us..

Comment: @Shanish Rajesh is right - some context of why you are trying to remove the closing tags would be helpful.

Comment: @Rajesh: you r right, actually am using the same table for more than one functions like add, delete. for this am trying to remove `</tr></table>` and bind my values and I can add the close tag again

Comment: @Shanish I would rethink the way you're doing this then - consider [Isaac's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11009577/582278).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know what's for do you need this, but according to your code you could do it like this:

```
if (myTable.substr(0, (myTable.length-12)) === '</tr></table>') {
  myTable = myTable.substr(0, (myTable.length-12));
}
```

Comment: thanks Blowski and shershen, with this `substr` method, I can remove the last 12 characters. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I think a better practice and better solution for your problem would be to create your table like this

```
$('<table></table>',{
    width:'100%', id:'yourTable', and many other values 
    }).appendTo('#insertTableIntoHere');
```

And then when you want to add any tr you will just do

```
 $('#yourTable').append($('<td></td>',{custom attributes}) );
```

the same when you need to append any other `<tr>` all of these are better practices when using jQuery, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you might try to do

```
$('table td:last-child').remove();
```

Just make sure you are targeting the right element

Comment: thanks for the response, the problem is am a novice in jQuery, I want to remove `</tr></table>` exactly in the tail.

Comment: This is removing the last `<td>` NOT the `</tr></table>`. Since we're removing closing tags but not the opening ones, we are not removing nodes, and hence cannot use jQuery selectors and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myTable = myTable.replace('</tr><table>', '')
```

Comment: The OP says "the *last* `</tr></table>` from the table". In other words, if there is a nested table, this will remove *all* of the closing tags.

Comment: @Blowski this is a string, we can see it, which `if`?

Comment: @Blowski: you r right, am using more than one `</tr></table>` here, thats what I need to remove the last one exactly

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you

```
myTable.replace('</tr><table>', '');
```

Comment: am using more than one </tr></table> here, thats what I need to remove the last one exactly

Answer (score 0):

Use the string replace

```
    myTable =  myTable.replace("</tr></table>","");
```

Its better to the string replace for your problem